# ViewModel и дочерние VM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Добрый день.

1. Имеется крупный проект на MVVM Light.
2. Есть главная VM в которой куча дочерних.
3. В главной VM определена куча приватных переменных на каждую дочернюю
   VM (порядка 30 штук) - это у нас так сказать кэш VM.

Т.е. если VM уже создана, то забрать из переменной. Можно было бы запихнуть все дочерние VM в коллекцию(Observable,List etc.), но проблема в том что одна VM может быть открыта дважды. Пример: редактор компании вызывается для наших компаний с одними параметрами и для не-клиентов с другими. Итог должно быть 2 VM в кэше одного типа (CompanyEditVM). Сейчас есть вариант хранить эти VM в dictionary, но к сожалению как ключ придется использовать обычный string...или нет?

**Мой вопрос: есть ли у вас какие либо наработки по работе с дочерними VM ??? Есть ли примеры? (искал в гугл, как-то хило)**

Доп.инфо: 
VM создаются через ViewModelFactory, которая использует контейнер Unity. 
Дочерние VM отображаются в единственном экемпляре на главной форме в UserControl.

Comment: Простите, вам _нужно_, чтобы каждой VM была только одна штука? Или некоторых _нужно_ ровно две штуки? И ещё, как вы их различаете — по типу?

Comment: Приведите релевантный кусок вашей главной VM.

Comment: к примеру есть 2 кнопки: клац на одну -> появляется VM1, выставляем свойство vm1.prop1 = 1. Отображаем. клац на кнопку 2 -> отображается VM1 выставляем св-во vm2.prop1 = 2. Т.е. в определенных условиях должна создаваться VM1, а в других условиях  браться из кеша.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, эту проблему надо решать на уровне `ViewModelFactory`. Пусть она проверяет входные параметры и реализует нужную политику кеширования подчинённых VM. Например, если входные параметры для `CompanyEditVM` встречались раньше, пусть выдаётся копия из кеша.

Таким образом, политика создания подчинённых уходит во `ViewModelFactory` (одну или несколько), а остальной код каждый раз единообразно запрашивает VM у Factory.

Может быть, можно переложить это задание на Unity, но это в любом случае внутреннее дело Factory.

Comment: точно! спасибо, много хороших идей появилось, надеюсь все получится. Обратил внимание, что вы очень часто сидите в разделе про MVVM и ваши ответы мне нравятся. Вопрос в большей степени был адресован именно вам. Еще раз спасибо!)

Comment: @cvvlad: Пожалуйста! Всегда рад хорошему вопросу!